# Missing first char in bufferedreader

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

I have an android device and a server. The server can transmit a message telling the device to disconnect from wifi. To get a quick idea how it does so, here's a psudo sequence diagram:

[image: Pseudo sd]

Now the fun thing is, when the client reconnects, and the server transmits a message, sometimes that message is missing the first character, sometimes it's the next message. Non the less, it happens pretty quickly after the client reconnects.

And example-loop is shown here, seen from the serverside:

```
     while (true) {
        server_.transmitMessage("SLAVE", "WIFI");
        Thread.sleep(40000);
        System.out.println("Should be back");
        server_.transmitMessage("SLAVE", "Hi wififims");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
```

And the output from the Android-device:

```
03-05 15:36:01.200 17152-17180/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Conecting to 192.168.1.77:6650
03-05 15:36:11.080 17152-17181/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Received: WIFI
03-05 15:36:11.080 17152-17181/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Client expecting disconnect.
03-05 15:36:11.080 17152-17181/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Expecting disconnect.
03-05 15:36:11.590 17152-17181/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Killing wifi
03-05 15:36:16.660 17152-17181/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Enableing wifi
03-05 15:36:31.760 17152-17181/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Conecting to 192.168.1.77:6650
03-05 15:36:51.550 17152-17181/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Received: Hi wififims
03-05 15:36:56.780 17152-17181/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Received: IFI
```

As shown on the last line, the second message sent after the reconnect is flawed on receival. It was supposed to be "WIFI". If I let the program run for a while, let's say 5 minutes, suddenly the missing characters comes with another message:

```
03-05 15:52:32.480 17152-17181/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Received: WWWWWWWWWWWWIFI
```

**Server**

Here is the listening server shown:

```
    public void startListening(int port) {
    this.port = port;
    canceled_ = false;
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("Listening for incomming connections on port " + port);
            serverSocket_ = new ServerSocket(port);
            while (!canceled_) {
                ServerClient serverClient = new ServerClient(serverSocket_.accept(), networkReceiver, server_);
                serverClient.listen();
                serverClient.setIdWithoutTransmission(Long.toString(clientId++));
                this.ServerClientList_.add(serverClient);
                networkReceiver.onNewClient(serverClient.getId());
                System.out.println("Client connected from:" + serverClient.getClientSocket().getInetAddress() +
                                           serverClient.getClientSocket().getPort());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            handleDisconnect();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

This set's the local ServerClient to a listen state:

```
  public void listen() {
    this.canceled_ = false;
    new Thread(() -> {
        while (!canceled_) {
            try {
                if (clientSocket_ == null) {
                    System.out.println("Socket is null, returning from listening");
                    return;
                }
                clientSocket_.setSoTimeout(0);
                BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket_
                                                                                               .getInputStream()));
                String msg = inFromClient.readLine();
                if (msg == null) {
                    super.handleDisconnect();
                    return;
                }
                if (handleMessage(msg))
                    continue;
                networkReceiver.onNewMessage(msg);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                super.handleDisconnect();
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

When the server transmits to a client:

```
    public void transmitMessage(String id, String msg) {
    for (ServerClient ServerClient : ServerClientList_) {
        System.out.println("Does  " + id + " equals "+ ServerClient.getId());
        if (ServerClient.getId().equals(id)) {
            ServerClient.transmitMessage(msg);
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Couldn't find ServerClient.");
}
```

and the actual method on the serverclient:

```
    public void transmitMessage(String message) {
    if (clientSocket_ == null || !clientSocket_.isBound()) {
        System.out.println("Not connected, can't transmit. Make sure you are connected to the host\nClientsocket " +
                                   "is null or not bound");
        return;
    }

    DataOutputStream outToServer = null;
    try {
        outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket_.getOutputStream());
        outToServer.writeBytes(message + '\n');
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error while writing to socket - message not delivered");

    }

}
```

Handling a disconnect on the server (The client sends a message which is handled).

```
 private boolean handleMessage(final String msg) {
    if (msg.equals(EXPECT_DISCONNECT_MSG)) {
        EXPECT_DISCONNECT_FLAG(true);
        return true;
    }
```

And when the ServerClients listener then catches the exception, it then sees the flag raised, and calls:

```
    protected void handleExpectedDisconnect() {
    server_.lossOfClient(this);
    this.canceled_ = true;
    finalizeSockets();
}
```

The lossOfClient is simply:

```
    public void lossOfClient(final ServerClient serverClient) {
    this.ServerClientList_.remove(serverClient);
    System.out.println("Removed client with ID " + serverClient.getId());
    System.out.println("Size: " + server_.getServerClientList().size());
}
```

**Client**

The client is initialized with

```
    public void connectAndListen(String host, int port) {
    this.canceled_ = false;
    try {
        System.out.println("Conecting to " + host + ":" + port);
        clientSocket_ = new Socket(host, port);
        clientSocket_.setSoTimeout(2000);
        listen();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Socket error - restarting");
    }

}

   public void listen() {
    this.canceled_ = false;
    new Thread(() -> {
        while (!canceled_) {
            try {
                if (clientSocket_ == null) {
                    System.out.println("Socket is null, returning from listening");
                    return;
                }
                clientSocket_.setSoTimeout(0);
                BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket_
                                                                                               .getInputStream()));
                String msg = inFromClient.readLine();
                if (msg == null) {
                    super.handleDisconnect();
                    return;
                }
                if (handleMessage(msg))
                    continue;
                networkReceiver.onNewMessage(msg);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                super.handleDisconnect();
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

And the disconnect:

```
   public void disconnect() {
    try {
        if (clientSocket_ != null && clientSocket_.isBound()) {
            System.out.println("Client expecting disconnect.");
            EXPECT_DISCONNECT_FLAG(true);
            transmitMessage(EXPECT_DISCONNECT_MSG);
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        finalizeSockets();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Coudln't inform receiver about expected disconnect."); 

    }
}

    public void finalizeSockets() {
    if (clientSocket_ != null && clientSocket_.isBound()) {
        try {
            if (!clientSocket_.isClosed())
                clientSocket_.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't close clientsocket");
        }
        clientSocket_ = null;
    }

}
```

Can anybody tell me, what I'm doing wrong? Why does the received message after a disconnect/reconnect - which is new sockets on both sides, fail to transmit the whole message?

**EDIT:**

Tried to flush the outputstream, to make sure all bytes are sent, though that didn't help.
Best regards.

**EDIT II**

Tried:

```
 DataOutputStream outToServer = null;
BufferedReader inFromClient = null;
```

and only creating them when they're null. When the socket is closed, these are set to null. Same problem:

```
03-05 18:05:00.000 11383-11427/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: 

Conecting to 192.168.1.77:6650
03-05 18:05:06.470 11383-11428/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Received: Hi wififims
03-05 18:05:11.490 11383-11428/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Received: WIFI
03-05 18:05:11.490 11383-11428/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Client expecting disconnect.
03-05 18:05:11.490 11383-11428/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Expecting disconnect.
03-05 18:05:12.000 11383-11428/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Killing wifi
03-05 18:05:17.090 11383-11428/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Enableing wifi
03-05 18:05:32.180 11383-11428/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Conecting to 192.168.1.77:6650
03-05 18:05:51.530 11383-13368/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Received: i wififims
03-05 18:05:56.560 11383-13368/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Received: IFI
03-05 18:06:38.300 11383-11428/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Received: HWHi wififims
03-05 18:06:43.340 11383-13368/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Received: WIFI
```

**EDIT III**
With a wireshark trace I could see that sometimes a message like "WIFI" was splitted into two packages, W in one, and IFI in the other. This seemed like the reason, so I tried:

```
public void listen(){
    ....
            byte[] arbytes = new byte[inFromServer.readInt()];
            int length = arbytes.length;
            inFromServer.read(arbytes,0,length);
....
}
```

and in transmit

```
public void transmitMessage(String message) {

....
    try {
        if(outToServer == null)
            outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket_.getOutputStream());

        byte[] databyes = message.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        outToServer.writeInt(databyes.length);
        outToServer.write(databyes);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error while writing to socket - message not delivered");

    }

}
```

Though still no luck:

```
03-05 20:01:10.810 27328-27353/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: 

Conecting to 192.168.1.77:6650
03-05 20:01:21.600 27328-27354/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Received: WIFI
03-05 20:01:21.600 27328-27354/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Client expecting disconnect.
03-05 20:01:21.600 27328-27354/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Expecting disconnect.
03-05 20:01:22.110 27328-27354/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Killing wifi
03-05 20:01:27.200 27328-27354/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Enableing wifi
03-05 20:01:42.270 27328-27354/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Conecting to 192.168.1.77:6650
03-05 20:01:42.290 27328-27354/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Percent bad: 0.0
03-05 20:02:01.560 27328-28467/com.example.bla.psedowifidims I/System.out: Received: ififims�������
```

Comment: Hey would you change this outToServer.writeBytes(message + '\n');
 in the transmitMessage to this outToServer.writeBytes((message + '\n').getBytes());

Comment: Well, the writeBytes takes a string, doesn't it? So if I use getBytes, I'd have to use String.ValueOf on it, and then it simply received as "Received: [B@682a0b20" :(

Comment: Change the inFromServer into a DataInputStream and use the readFully and tell me please

Comment: @Mehdi, Same. I've also tried all manual (Size + data), and read/writeUTF - same problem. It seems it happens when a TCP retransmission has happened. :/

Comment: Did you try manual flushing with the DataOutput/Input Streams?

Comment: Yup. When I manually create the data arrays, I can see in wireshark that the whole array is transmittet in one package. But somehow, mostly after a TCP retransmission, the socket reads some bull, and think it should read more bytes than it should. I somehow think it gets the bad package, and then also gets the retransmitted package, but I just can't understand how.

Comment: You might have something wrong in the server try to post your server as class's and not just code sample so i could better understand it

Comment: Hell, it worked with a printwriter as transmitter. Think it's some android-thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright - I went through a lot of trials. I tried manually sending the number og bytes going to be transmitted, followed by the data, and then doing accordingly at the client-side.

While this worked, when a TCP-Retransmission happened, somehow it got the wrong size on the retransmitted package. This was the same for WriteUTF and so on.

Somehow - after a lot of tries, I changed the transmitter to use a PrintWriter.

```
    public void transmitMessage(String message) {
    if (clientSocket_ == null || !clientSocket_.isBound()) {
        System.out.println("Not connected, can't transmit. Make sure you are connected to the host\nClientsocket " +
                "is null or not bound");
        return;
    }

    try {
        if (outToServer == null)
            outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket_.getOutputStream());


        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket_.getOutputStream())), true);
        pw.println(message);
        pw.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error while writing to socket - message not delivered");

    }

}
```

And now everything works - also during retransmissions. 
If anybody can tell me **WHY** this works, I'd really appreciate it!